# Python Merge 2 dataframes on multiple columns with OR

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem, struggling with how to merge/join 2 dataframes so I get the result below:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : [ '02/22', '02/22', '02/22', '02/22', '02/22'],
                    'house' : ['house1','house2','house3','house4', 'house5'],
                     'code':  ['x', 'y', 'z', 'b', 'c'],
                   'text':    ['xxx', 'xxx','xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'],
                   'status_02/22':  ['open1', 'open2', 'open3', 'open4', 'open5']})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : [ '03/22', '03/22', '03/22', '03/22', '03/22','03/22','03/22'],
                    'house' : ['house1','house22','house4','house3', 'house51', 'house9','house10'],
                     'code':  ['x', 'y', 'nan', 'z', 'c', 'g', 'r'],
                   'text':    ['xxx', 'xxx','xxx', 'Nan', 'xxx', 'bbb', 'bbb'],
                   'status_03/22':  ['open1', 'open2', 'nan4', 'open3', 'open5', 'open', 'open']})

print(df_1)
print(df_2)


    date   house code text status_02/22
0  02/22  house1    x  xxx        open1
1  02/22  house2    y  xxx        open2
2  02/22  house3    z  xxx        open3
3  02/22  house4    b  xxx        open4
4  02/22  house5    c  xxx        open5
    date    house code text status_03/22
0  03/22   house1    x  xxx        open1
1  03/22  house22    y  xxx        open2
2  03/22   house4  nan  xxx         nan4
3  03/22   house3    z  Nan        open3
4  03/22  house51    c  xxx        open5
5  03/22   house9    g  bbb         open
6  03/22  house10    r  bbb         open
```

1. Merge df_1 and df2 on the 'code' column,
2. 'code' column can go to 'Nan' so those unmerged on 'code', try to marge on the column 'house'
3. those left unmerged concatenate to the bottom of the table (blue color)

> ```
> new_df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : [ '02/22', '02/22', '02/22', '02/22', '02/22','03/22','03/22'],
>                     'house' : ['house1','house2','house3','house4', 'house5', 'house9', 'house10'],
>                      'code':  ['x', 'y', 'z', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'r'],
>                    'text':    ['xxx', 'xxx','xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'bbb', 'bbb'],
>                    'status_02/22':  ['open', 'open', 'open', 'open', 'open','open', 'open'],
>                    'status_03/22':  ['open', 'open', 'open', 'Nan', 'open','open', 'open']})
> new_df
> ```

[image]

I made a bit of progress on this,
steps 1 and 2 merging on columns 'code' and 'house'

```
res = df_1.merge(df_2[['code','status_03/22']], on='code', how="left")

res.update(df_1.merge(df_2[['house','status_03/22']], on='house', how="left"))
res

    date   house code text status_02/22 status_03/22
0  02/22  house1    x  xxx        open1        open1
1  02/22  house2    y  xxx        open2        open2
2  02/22  house3    z  xxx        open3        open3
3  02/22  house4    b  xxx        open4         nan4
4  02/22  house5    c  xxx        open5        open5
```

I am still missing the 3rd step,
make 2 lists from res 'code' and 'house'

```
code_list = list(set(res['code']))
house_list = list(set(res['house']))
```

concatenate df_2 to res, rows not containing values from house_list & code_list.

```
5  03/22   house9    g  bbb         open
6  03/22  house10    r  bbb         open
```

Comment: It is unclear from your question, which is the final desired result. Is it the result you show after you concatenate?  Or is it something different?